# Большое количество запросов - какое лучшее решение на Python?

Tags: python, requests

Есть задача - долбить в API сайта как можно больше запросов в секунду, пока не будет получен нужный ответ, лимит позволяет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое решение лучше всего использовать для этой задачи? Я написал код на мультипроцессинге, добавив в него задержку в виде time.sleep для каждого процесса разную, чтобы запросы шли друг за другом, но мне кажется, что это очень топорный подход и + много ресурсов уходит, наверное, на создание и закрытие процессов. AIOHTTP, THREADING, MULTIPROCESSING? Что лучше всего подходит для этой задачи? Спасибо!

Comment: Мультипроцессинг или нет - сетевая карта у Вас одна

Comment: Ну если вы добавляете time.sleep, то фраза «как можно больше запросов в секунду» автоматически становится бессмысленной

Comment: И фраза «чтобы запросы шли друг за другом» автоматически делает бессмысленной использование threading, multiprocessing или нескольких task'ов в asyncio

Comment: @andreymal я понял, что очень плохо сформулировал свое сообщение, спасибо. time.sleep добавил в мультипроцессинг, потому что мне нужно, чтобы запросы шли с одинаковым промежутком времени, если без него - то запросы идут пачками, отправились все запросы - прошло 0.5 секунды и потом только отправилась снова пачка запросов со всех процессов. Моя задача - чтобы запросы шли с одинаковым промежутком времени и чтобы этот промежуток времени был как можно короче. То есть, как бы работа в один поток по логике, но скорость нужна выше, поэтому нужно что-то дополнительно использовать.

Comment: Тогда что означает "чтобы запросы шли друг за другом"? Вы хотите дожидаться ответа на предыдущий запрос перед началом следующего? Или вам пофиг и вы хотите отправлять следующий запрос даже если предыдущий ещё не закончился?

Comment: @andreymal Смотрите, у меня сейчас есть код для мультипроцессинга, который, к примеру, работает в 10 процессов. Один процесс отправляет запрос, следующий процесс отправляет запрос через 0.1 секунду и так далее. И потом они также по очереди в 0.1 секунду отдают ответ. То есть, получается, что каждую 0.1 секунду у меня уходит запрос на сервер. Когда хоть один ответ - который мне нужен,, все запросы прекращают идти. При этом может быть так, что несколько последних запросов могут быть лишними, ничего страшного. Мне нужно понять, можно ли, используя другой инструмент, делать это чаще.  Спасибо!

Comment: В вечном цикле создавать asyncio-таски десять раз в секунду до тех пор, пока какой-нибудь таск не поставит отметку, что он получил от сервера нужный ответ. Только желательно отслеживать число текущих запущенных тасков, чтобы случайно не оказалось, что цикл создал миллионы зависших запросов

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое!

Comment: Хотя если несколько запросов могут работать одновременно, то тут уже пора задуматься о штуках вроде пула соединений, потому что HTTP/1.1 не позволяет делать несколько одновременных запросов в одном соединении, а каждый раз создавать новое соединение может быть слишком медленно. Если сервер поддерживает HTTP/2 (который вроде как поддерживает одновременные запросы), то может быть практичнее вместо aiohttp взять httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тексте вопроса написано что попало, но вот что я понял из комментариев:

- нужно отправлять запросы с определённой частотой (но чем чаще, тем лучше);
- перед отправкой следующего запроса ждать завершения предыдущего не нужно;
- как только на какой-то запрос будет получен нужный ответ, работа завершается (то, что могут остаться другие ещё не завершённые запросы, не критично).

Приведённый ниже код асинхронно делает вот это вот всё. На случай, если сервер поддерживает протокол HTTP/2, я взял библиотеку httpx (aiohttp не поддерживает этот протокол).

<sup>(**Предупреждение:** этот код долбит сервер десятью запросами в секунду, не запускайте его бездумно!)</sup>

```py
import asyncio
import logging

import httpx  # pip install httpx[http2]

# Сюда какой-нибудь таск запишет нужный ответ, если он его получит
response = None

async def send_request(sem, idx, client):
    global response

    try:
        r = await client.get("https://localhost/test.txt")

        if r.status_code == 200 and "yes" in r.text:  # Проверка на нужный ответ
            print(idx, "yes!")
            if response is None:
                response = r
        else:
            print(idx, "nope")

    except Exception:
        # В асинхронном коде важно не забывать обрабатывать возможные ошибки
        # Если случится ошибка, печатаем её в лог
        # (но только если не был ранее получен нужный ответ,
        # чтобы не флудить зазря)
        if response is None:
            logging.exception("Failed to send request %d", idx)

    finally:
        # Не забываем сообщить семафору, что запрос закончился
        sem.release()

async def main():
    # С помощью семафора можно ограничить максимальное число одновременных
    # запросов, чтобы случайно не насоздавать миллионы их
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

    # Здесь можно подкрутить лимиты httpx, но если у нас есть свой семафор,
    # то они наверное не очень нужны
    limits = httpx.Limits(max_keepalive_connections=None, max_connections=None)
    client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True, timeout=httpx.Timeout(10.0))

    requests_count = 0

    async with client:
        while response is None:
            await sem.acquire()
            requests_count += 1
            asyncio.create_task(send_request(sem, requests_count, client))

            # Этот sleep регулирует частоту отправки запросов
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

        # Здесь можно сделать что-нибудь с полученным нужным ответом
        print("Response:", response.text)

    # Примечание: если после выхода из блока «async with client»
    # ещё остались таски, ожидающие ответа на запрос, то они выдадут
    # ошибку из-за того, что client уже закрылся (но это вроде не критично)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего здесь подойдет aiohttp благодаря асинхронности под капотом.

Пример кода запроса:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://example.com') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Пример взят из официальной [документации](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request).

Comment: Если у автора задача «чтобы запросы шли друг за другом», то может случайно оказаться, что накладные расходы на асинхронность лишь ухудшат производительность

Comment: Спасибо большое!